# Find matching individuals in two datasets in R

Tags: r, functional-programming

There are a lot of matching "X" and "Y" questions in R on this site but I think I have a new one. I have two datasets, one is shorter (500 rows) and has one entry per individual. The second is bigger (~20,000 rows) and an individual can have multiple entries. Both have columns for date of birth and gender. My goal is to find people represented in both datasets and to start by finding date of birth and gender matches. My python influenced brain came up with this horrifically slow solution:

```
dob_big <- c('1975-05-04','1968-02-16','1985-02-28','1980-12-12','1976-06-06','1979-06-24','1981-01-28',
         '1985-01-16','1984-03-04','1979-06-26','1988-12-22','1975-10-02','1968-02-04','1972-02-01',
         '1981-08-06','1989-01-21','1956-06-25','1986-01-19','1980-03-24','1965-08-16')
gender_big <- c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0)
big_df <- data_frame(date_birth = dob_big, gender = gender_big)
dob_small <- c('1985-01-16','1984-03-04','1979-06-26')
gender_small <- c(1,0,1)
small_df <- data_frame(date_birth = dob_small, gender = gender_small)

for (i in 1:length(big_df$date_birth)) {
    save_row <- FALSE
    for (j in 1:length(small_df$date_birth)) {
        if (big_df$date_birth[i] == small_df$date_birth[j]
        & big_df$gender[i] == small_df$gender[j]) {
            print(paste("Match found at ",i,",",j))
            save_row <- TRUE
        }
    }
    if (save_row == TRUE) {
    matches <- c(matches,i)
    }
}
```

Is there a more functional solution that would run faster in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`which`could be an alternative.

```
paste0("Match found at ",
       which(paste(big_df$date_birth, big_df$gender) %in% 
               paste(small_df$date_birth, small_df$gender)),
       ", ",
       which(paste(small_df$date_birth, small_df$gender) %in% 
               paste(big_df$date_birth, big_df$gender)),
       collapse = "; ")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to find those that are represented in both, you could do a [merge](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/merge)

```
merge(big_df,small_df, by = c("date_birth","gender"))
```

Comment: I guess you mean `merge(small_df,bigg_df)`